# Vue Error: Expecting Boolean, but receive True/False String instead

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm attempting to only render a component if value is true, however I'm receiving the following error:

```
  Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "selectable". Expected Boolean, got String with value "true / false".
```

I render the component as follows:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <InternalTable :participants="participants"selectable="true"></InternalTable>
  </div>
</template>
```

With the props inside that component looking like this:

```
    export default {
  props: {
    participants:
        {
          type: Array,
          default: null
        },
      selectable: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
      }
  },
```

I'm not sure how to better phrase that, so reaching out here for ideas om how best to fix this.

Comment: If you want Vue to interpret prop value as Javascript instead of simple string, you need to use `v-bind:selectable="true"` or `:selectable="true"` instead of just `selectable="true"` (which is always interpreted as string value)

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Passing-a-Boolean

Answer (score 2):

You missed `:` or `v-bind:selectable="true"`.

Answer (score 1):

this will solve your issue

```
<InternalTable :participants="participants" :selectable="true"></InternalTable>
```